# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Client.Framework' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I want to Implement active-directory-scim-provisioning from scratch and for guidance I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-scim-provisioning) example. I have created a basic asp.net WebAPI application and installed this `SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement` nuget package.

Project Builds fine but while running the webapi project I am getting following error.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.Client.Framework' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

[image: here is image]

I think the issue might related to DLL loading or version issue, but again I am **installing package from NuGet**, I am little confus

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Did you install the [ADAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)?

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT it is installed along with `SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagement` package. I updated it to latest version still the issue persist.

Comment: I am having the same exact problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same problem. I managed to get it to work in VS2017 by going to;

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects -> Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects.

I've not tried to deploy the project to our servers yet, but it is running on localhost now.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your IIS version from 32 to 64 bit you need to ensure that all of your components are 64 bit compatible.